# If JSON returns empty display message in <table>

Tags: javascript, json

I have a table that is populated by **JSON** from a **API** and on occasion will not have data.

How can I return a message "No Data" within the `<tr>` of the table below `if` no object `label` is found in the **JSON**?

I believe that I am defining the empty data is already being achieved with

```
this.forEach(function(item) {
    type = path.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a[b]
    }, item) || 'null';
    if (!result[type])
      result[type] = [];
    result[type].push(item);
  });
  return result;
```

but how can I return the `No Data` within the table?

This snippet below shows the table and if you change the date within the API URL to, for example, `2018-01-14,2018-01-15` you will get no return on the data for each date.

```js
$.getJSON('https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/index.php?module=API&method=DevicesDetection.getBrowsers&idSite=2&period=day&date=2017-12-17,2018-01-05&format=json&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff', (browser_data) => {
  Array.prototype.groupBy = function(key) {
    var path = key.split('.');
    var result = {};
    try {
      this.forEach(function(item) {
        // es6: path.reduce((a, b) => a[b], item)
        type = path.reduce(function(a, b) {
          return a[b]
        }, item) || 'null';
        if (!result[type])
          result[type] = [];
        result[type].push(item);
      });
      return result;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return {};
    }
  };

  function getPropertySum(key, arr) {
    return arr.reduce((a, b) => (key in b ? a + b[key] : a), 0)
  }
  // one array of all dates
  let browserCode = ('segment');
  let flattenArr = [].concat.apply([], Object.values(browser_data));
  // object of grouped dates by device
  let groups = flattenArr.groupBy('label');
  let table = document.getElementById('browserTable');
  table.innerHTML = '';
  Object.keys(groups).forEach(function(label) {
    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    let logw = document.createElement('td');
    let logo = document.createElement('img');
    let lab = document.createElement('td');
    let nbv = document.createElement('td');
    let nbu = document.createElement('td');
    row.appendChild(logw);
    row.appendChild(lab);
    row.appendChild(nbv);
    row.appendChild(nbu);
    logw.appendChild(logo);

    // Get the logo property and use split on the string
    logoProperty = getPropertySum('logo', groups[label]);
    var logoPropSplit = logoProperty.split("/");
    var logoName = logoPropSplit[logoPropSplit.length - 1];
    // End of edit

    logo.src = 'https://discovrbookings.com/wp-content/themes/discovr-application/assets/img/browser-icons/' + logoName;
    lab.innerHTML = label;
    nbv.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_visits', groups[label]);
    nbu.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_uniq_visitors', groups[label]);
    table.appendChild(row);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="browserTable">


</table>
```

Currently, it shows as

[image: Current]

and I would like this to show as

[image: With query]

Comment: Check for length of array. If it is zero then display "no data" in row otherwise iterate over whole data.

Comment: Thank you @Lalit. The array will never be zero as the rows are sorted by date. However, the `label` in which the data is grouped by will be. This is JSON with no data for each date `{"2018-01-14":[],"2018-01-15":[]}`, whilst `{"2017-12-17":[],"2017-12-18":[{"label":"Desktop","nb_uniq_visitors":1}]}` is with data. Is there any chance you can put your suggestion into an answer with more detail. Cheers.

Comment: Can you show an example of what an empty return looks like?

Comment: @Darren You will have to iterate through json first to check if all the values are empty.

Comment: As a side note, you might want to consider using a templating library such as Handlebars which would simply this code no end

Comment: Thank you @DarrenSweeney. I have used Handlebars in the past and was rather fond of it. In this case, I started with something that was meant to be simple and it has grown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `groups` object will either contain data or not. I added code to check how many keys it has. If it has more than 0, then it runs your current code to build the table showing the data. Then I added a new code section that checks if it has 0 keys. If so, it builds a simpler table that shows "No Data".

See working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/37twkv1c/1/) here. In the jsfiddle, I've included two `url` definitions. One is commented out. Comment out the opposite one to see the table with data or without data.

And see relevant code below:

```
if (Object.keys(groups).length > 0) {
  Object.keys(groups).forEach(function(label) {
    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    let logw = document.createElement('td');
    let logo = document.createElement('img');
    let lab = document.createElement('td');
    let nbv = document.createElement('td');
    let nbu = document.createElement('td');
    row.appendChild(logw);
    row.appendChild(lab);
    row.appendChild(nbv);
    row.appendChild(nbu);
    logw.appendChild(logo);

    // Get the logo property and use split on the string
    logoProperty = getPropertySum('logo', groups[label]);
    var logoPropSplit = logoProperty.split("/");
    var logoName = logoPropSplit[logoPropSplit.length - 1];
    // End of edit

    logo.src = 'https://discovrbookings.com/wp-content/themes/discovr-application/assets/img/browser-icons/' + logoName;
    lab.innerHTML = label;
    nbv.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_visits', groups[label]);
    nbu.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_uniq_visitors', groups[label]);
    table.appendChild(row);
  });
}

if (Object.keys(groups).length == 0) {
    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    let nodata = document.createElement('td');
    row.appendChild(nodata);
    nodata.innerHTML = "No Data"
    table.appendChild(row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Dr. Cool. That is stellar.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: I have accepted your answer but it says the bounty can be accepted in 23 hours. I'll check back tomorrow and accept this. Thank you again.